# execute repetitive background task

Tags: android

I need a suggestion for my application, there is a DB which contains lot of events timestamp in milliseconds.

Now in interval of each one minute from AlarmManager I fetch required milliseconds from database and shows notification.

Is there any other idea for this task from which I don't need to run AlarmManager in each one minute, like services or any other idea.

I think using AlarmManager at every one minute is battery consuming.

Comment: Just some clarification: You have an app that reads timestamps from a database every minute, at which point it shows a notification containing some information about the timestamps? How are the timestamps added to the database? and how frequently?

Comment: @iambeanie actually timestamps are stored on creation of events(weekly, yearly and daily). I executes a SQL query from AlarmManager which fetch timestamps from DB between some ranges(from current time to next one minute). An if it find any or more it sends notification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html).

Example can be found [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/12/example-of-using-timer-and-timertask-on.html).

**[EDIT]** - As per @Balaji_Kandasamy comment including the essential parts

```
    // Create a Timer task
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Implement the task you want to perform periodically
        }
    };
    //create a new Timer
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    //specify the time interval in seconds after which task should run periodically
    int seconds = 60; // in your case as per question one minute
    //schedule your timer to execute perodically
    timer.schedule(task, seconds*1000);
```

At the end (on button click or something) cancel the timer when task is done.

```
    timer.cancel();
```

**[EDIT]** - As per @Akhilesh_Mani comment including the BOOT Issue.

You can Implement a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` action as :

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Perform Your opeartion to start a Service
            // In service execute the TimerTask
            // So that even if phone shut down your task
            // starts as boot completes
            // Start the same service when your application is launched
            // or installed for first time as you wish

        }

 }
```

Manifest entry :

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.BootCompleteReceiver " >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Aduait Pokhriyal is Timer restarts itself in situations like phone goes off?  Like AlarmManager has ability to restarts itself.

Comment: No , AlarmManager uses pending Intent so even if phone goes switches off pending intent is received at particular time period. But Timer task has a life cycle dependent on the Application.

Comment: @AduaitPokhriyal But my need is to active that task forever. I think using AlarmManager at every one minute is much power consuming.

Comment: Check my edited answer now. You can use the same Timer task now just start it if there is booting of device.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create a background sticky service.
2. Inside that service start an AsyncTask.
3. Inside the doInBackground of the AsyncTask, you can use Thread.sleep(millis). Which will make it stop for that time.
4. When the time elapses, inside the onPostExecute of AsyncTask, you can do whatever UI related stuff you want and in the end, create a new instance of the AsyncTask and execute it again.

Make sure you run the AsyncTask inside ThreadPoolExecutor, else you wont achieve parallelism in execution of threads